# Is it good to use asyncio, multiprocessing or multithreading for post requests

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a story where dynamically filled xml document are sent through a web service. Here is what I'm using in python3.x:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'g', 'h', 'm', 'e'], 'B': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'],'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

headers = {'content-type':'text/xml'}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['B'] == 'a':
        a_wsdl = 'wsdl url'
        body = """
        <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
          <soap:Fault>
          """+str(row['C'])+"""
          </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        """
        
        requests.post(a_wsdl, data=body, headers=headers)
        
    elif row['B'] == 'b':
        b_wsdl = 'wsdl url'
        body = """
        <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
          <soap:Fault>
          """+str(row['A'])+"""
          </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        """
        
        requests.post(b_wsdl, data=body, headers=headers)
        
    else:
        c_wsdl = 'wsdl url'
        body = """
        <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
          <soap:Fault>
          """+str(row['A'])+str(row['C'])+"""
          </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        """
        
        requests.post(c_wsdl, data=body, headers=headers)
```

Using this, I got 1st, 3rd, 5th, 6th, 7th iterations were being posted successfully, but the 2nd and 4th records are missing.
I thought that occurred because of the common b_wsdl among 1st-5th which was assomptionably busy. So I thought of using time.sleep(), but this will let the code take longer time.

At that point I thought of using one of the three famous solutions: asyncio, multiprocessing, or multithreading. However, I'm not sure about which one suits my case since the busyness of the WSDL is an issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Spawning a subprocess per request is a lot of overhead you don't have need for here. I'd write off multiprocessing or subprocess off-the-bat. Just putting your requests on a queue, and having the worker that pops things off that queue and executes them have some logic for recognizing when the server returns responses indicating that it's busy or rate-limited should suffice.

Comment: ...and if your issue is indeed a problem with exceeding the maximum number of requests the remote server can handle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff may be worth reading.

Comment: ...beyond that, though, I'm not sure you're asking a question for which there exists a canonical right answer. Using asyncio for coroutines would get where you're going, but so would conventional threading; arguing between them would likely devolve into questions of opinion, which we try to avoid here.

Comment: I was actually looking for an example code that overcome this issue by using one of the three, multithreading or asyncio.  Anyway, you’re answer mentioning the queue which is the reasonable solution for that case. I will try it and then add it as an answer to my question to be useful for others.